# Swagger - how to add antiforgery token field in UI that'll be used in headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a few HTTP POST end points that require AntiForgery tokens being attached as a e.g header named `RequestVerificationToken`.

How can I add field named e.g "AFT Token" to every HTTP POST request on SwaggerUI that will use its value in header named `RequestVerificationToken`?

Is it possible to do from C# code or I have to edit some Swagger configs?

Sample endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromBody]Type data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You customize the request in a custom middleware.

For example:

```
  app.Use(next => context =>
    {
        string path = context.Request.Path.Value;

        if (
            string.Equals(path, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            string.Equals(path, "/swagger", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // The request token can be sent as a JavaScript-readable cookie, 
            // and Angular uses it by default.
            var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, 
                new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
        }

        return next(context);
    });
```

But I would not do this, as it would allow to access swagger in other environment except development.

What I would do is as fallows.

1.Allow swagger only in development.
2. AutoValidateAntiforgery only in non development.

Or create a custom middleware like in the example above and put it only in development environment.

Have a read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're sure about ``AutoValidate``? ``AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute allows to apply Anti-forgery token validation globally to all unsafe methods e.g. POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE. Thus you don't need to add [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute to each and every action that requires it.``

Comment: Isnt this what you want? To secure all the post,put,delete,path end point? Or you want to secure the specific one? Anyway the middleware should help you out get around the issue with swagger I think.

Comment: Swagger UI cannot send request to my Actions because it has no AntifogeryToken, so I have to manually remove ``[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`` attribute or find some work around. I'd want to be able to at least copy paste that token into SwaggerUI, so he'd be able to send requests

Comment: There is no such thing in swagger, yet. To copy paste it.

Comment: I'm facing the similar problem. How do I pass the antiforgery token to swagger UI?