# Unable to resolve service type for ValidateAntiforgeryToken Middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware, swagger-ui, antiforgerytoken

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/global-antiforgery-token-validation-in-asp-net-core) for implementing Antiforgery token middleware for my web application and I'm getting the following error when I try to run my Swagger API:

`: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery' while attempting to activate 'Middleware.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenMiddleware'.'`

Just implementing the middleware in *Configure()* in Startup.cs should work, correct (i.e. `app.UseMiddlware<ValidateAntiForgeryTokenMiddleware>();`)?

I guess I'm not entirely sure why it's unable to resolve IAntiforgery. Does this need to be set up in *ConfigureServices()*? I appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Are you calling the Api for this error? Check out this post, it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185446/swagger-how-to-add-antiforgery-token-field-in-ui-thatll-be-used-in-headers

Comment: @Chaodeng Thank you for the link! That did help, but now I'm having an issue with the header value, X-XSRF-Token not being present. I've asked Brando Zhang as well if there is a way to send the XSFR Token in a header in a POST request just in Swagger? A lot of posts I've seen have dealt with Swagger and a front-end where the token is intercepted in the front-end and then sent in a header in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, I think you may not inject the IAntiforgery service inside your startup.cs file. I suggest you could follow below codes to add it and solve the issue.

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {       
        services.AddAntiforgery();
   }
```

Comment: I followed Chaodeng's link and that did get rid of my error (I see an XSFR-Token cookie and a .AspNetCore.AntiForgery cookie) but now I get an error: `The required antiforgery header value "X-XSRF-TOKEN" is not present.` Now, I haven't quite built out my Angular-based front-end, but is that where I would check for the XSFR Token and then add the header to any POST request? Or is it possible to send the header in the request just through a Swagger POST?